# Count number of rows with activity within the last 7 days

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count

Basically, I have a field in my table that shows when the latest activity was in a regular unix timestamp.

What I need is a way to count the rows that have had activity in the past 7 days.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select count(*)
  from someTable
 where lastActivity > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 7 day)
```

Note that this is 7 days worth of seconds.

If you want activity of last 7 calendar days

```
select count(*)
  from someTable
 where lastActivity > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 day)
```

Comment: Thanks, this does the job! (I use the 2nd one)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM yourTable
WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), FROM_UNIXTIME(yourDateColumn)) <= 7
```

Comment: @Marco Thank you for pointing that out.  I have updated my answer to account for that.